# Crashlytics logs show multiple TextView.onMessure error. Any Help would be awesome

Tags: android

Firebase crashlytics shows multiple TextView.onMessure ArraOutOfBounds Exception on my Android App. I cannot figure out why.
Here's the Log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=26; index=26
   at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:343)
   at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:298)
   at android.text.Layout.measurePara(Layout.java:2115)
   at android.text.Layout.getDesiredWidthWithLimit(Layout.java:196)
   at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:8511)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:260)
   at com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView.onMeasure(MaterialCardView.java:160)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1308)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:350)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1638)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
   at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:99)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:831)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:825)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:704)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:716)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23173)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2726)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1580)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1863)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1468)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7207)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1012)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:823)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:758)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:998)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

[image]

Crashlytics does not show any specific locations where the crash occur. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you have this textView in some recyclerView? in such case you are seeing recreation of widgets.

Comment: Yes I have textviews on recyclerviews

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: there's a lot of activities in my app. I don't know exactly what should I post. Log doesn't say where the error is.